# PV solar panel is producing more than is possible according to its datasheet?

Tags: electrical-engineering, solar-energy, photovoltaics

I have a client in Belgium that has 16 DM400-M10-54HBB on his roof. On Saturday the 2nd of December 2023, the PV output was 3.95 kW, according to the log of the Huawei SUN2000 4.6KTL-L1 5 kVA inverter. This means 247 W per panel.

[image: Power on 2/12/2023]

This is the house, with the panels directed to the south-east:

[image: PV panels]

However, the irradiance was only 250-300 W/m<sup>2</sup> that day, according to multiple measurements accross the country (clear blue skies according to my naked eye). This is to be expected because we only get around 1100-1200 W/m<sup>2</sup> in summer and now it is winter.

[image: irradiance in Beerse]

[image: irradiance in Stabroek]

However, according to the datasheet, there is approximately 600 W/m<sup>2</sup> needed to produce this amount of power  (yellow line is drawn by me to indicate the produced peak power on that day). How is this possible?

[image: Datasheet power curves]
Datasheet source: https://www.elektrototaalmarkt.nl/amfile/file/download/file/3868/product/41786/

The data in the Huawei logs seems accurate..

Comment: And the ambient temperature? panels can work better on sunny cold days as found in winter months compared to hot sunny days as in summer. At least I have noticed that with our panels - also the snow in the garden reflects more sunlight onto the panels as the panels were at 70 degrees ie very vertical.

Comment: The ambient temperature was 2°C, which indeed gives approximately 10% extra yield compared to the P-V curve that I posted, which is at 25°C. However we are looking rather at a 2-300% unexplanable increase.

Comment: Measuring device was just likely wrong.  Probably managed to get into a region where it couldnt measure correctly

Comment: What region are you referring to? Voltagewise the panels are within the limits of the SUN2000 as the configuration is made up of 2 strings of 8 panels each.

Comment: Are you perhaps mixing W and Wh ? || You frequently use "W" where you seem to mean "Wh, or "Wh/day". In some cases you MAY mean W so it's is best that you edit it than that I do. (I started to but found areas where it was not certain). Gaisma says average in Antwerp in December is 0.55 kWh/day. Or 220Wh/day for your panels. That's an AVERAGE December day. || Your 250-300 kWh/m^2/day MAY be correct at present BUT your summer 1200 W / m^2 looks like Watts (not Wh) as average June Insolation is 4.89 kWh/m^2/day in June in Antwerp. [Gaisma Antwer[](https://www.gaisma.com/en/location/antwerp.html)

Comment: [dmm 400m DATASHEET HERE](https://www.vdh-solar.nl/Documents/92558ee2-2832-45f7-bac5-7aa4e0403b54.pdf). 400 w/m^2 at 25C and Am1.5. About +10% at 2C, as you say.

Comment: Limits of the device measuring voltage and current in order to report power to you, not of the panels.  The device may be implementing some form of filter to make up for its sampling (is it perhaps measuring voltage and current separately, reporting those and digitally calculating power?).  There is a lot that can go wrong in measuring devices, especially cost-effective, multi-function ones.  Limits for accurate measurements may involve what the charge controller was doing (many will limit how much current they draw from the panels to attempt maximizing power gains and the like).

Comment: I'm only talking about the instantanious power as this is the easiest to compare with the datasheet. (I should have said that the output power around noon was 3.95W peak to be clear). I choose 2/12 to compare because it was a bright sunny day. I would also not exclude the possibility that the solar irradiance ('zonnestraling') data is wrong. However, I enquired at our federal weather data collection center (KMI) and they are measuring with a radiometer that measures both direct and indirect light coming from all directions: https://www.kippzonen.com/Product/85/CNR4-Net-Radiometer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from fromwastetowind is correct that solar irradiance is published for a flat horizontal surface. I entered the time, latitude, and logitude for Brussels into the [NOAA ESRL Solar Position Calculator](https://gml.noaa.gov/grad/solcalc/azel.html). This gave a solar elevation of 16.87 degrees. Not knowing your customer's panel angles I just assumed a perfect angle 90 degrees to the incoming radiation (the best possible production). The best way to think about this calculation is that 0.29m^2 of solar radiation is spread out over the 1m^2 that the pyronometers measured.

The 861 watts per meter squared is a reasonable number because the radiation has to travel through more atmosphere at the high angle. And the roughly 600 watts per meter squared you figured from the spec sheet is reasonable for the not perfect angle on the fixed array.

[image]
[image]

Also note that in some cases mixed cloud cover (like shown in the OP photo) can cause an increase in local irradiance. The light that was headed to other locations on the earth's surface gets diffused and a portion of that light can end up at the solar array being analyzed. This can be a big problem for closed loop solar hot water systems and additional safety factory has to be considered when sizing the thermal load dump. [Article on mixed cloud cover irradiation spikes](https://www.pv-magazine.com/2020/07/14/solar-causes-highest-power-peaks-under-mixed-cloud-conditions/).

Answer (score 0):

I checked with the RMI (Royal Meteorology Institute in Belgium) and the sensor of the pyranometer is mounted horizontally. So this can only be compared with a solar panel that is also mounted horizontally. This explains the difference :)

Comment: So recalculate using trigonometry to work out the effective area...